# php_mcrypt.dll prevents PHP from loading

Tags: php, nginx, mcrypt

I am using WEMP (Engine-x / NGINX) and cannot seem to get mcrypt extension to load for phpmyadmin.

I've been tring to resolve this issue over an hour. I have tried puting libmcrypt.dll within the PHP root folder and windows/system32 and no luck.

There isn't a specific error. When I try to load the PHP exe the exe crashes instantly if I have got "extension=php_mcrypt.dll" within the php.ini file

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance